# Any transition in Java3D has to be an applet?

Tags: java, java-3d

I am trying to do a transition (rotation/translation) of a cube in Java3D.
Most of the examples on the net uses an applet.

My question is whether it is compulsory to use an applet or there is a way of doing the same without it?

If so kindly put some links too.

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @fvrghl The way I understand this question, it is **not** about recommending or finding anything. It is about the possibility to use Java3D **without** using it inside an applet.

Comment: @fvrghl I did not ask you to recommend or to find a new tool or a library. What I meant was to backup the answer with a suitable reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to be an applet.
Even JFrame (Swing) will do.